# python using len function with list as argument parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters

```
def infolist(alist):
    maxi=max(alist)
    mini=min(alist)
    leng=len(alist)
    print(maxi,mini,len)


thelist=(23,33,1,7)
print(thelist)
infolist(thelist)
print(thelist)
```

When I run the code it gives me the min and max but just says "built-in function len" for len, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're printing `len` instead of `leng`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to print `leng` not len. `len` is the builtin function.

```
def infolist(alist):
    maxi=max(alist)
    mini=min(alist)
    leng=len(alist)
    print(maxi,mini,leng)


thelist=(23,33,1,7)
print(thelist)
infolist(thelist)
print(thelist)
```

Comment: Correct, but we don't normally write full answers to "typo" questions, since they are unlikely to help future readers. The system tries to automatically clean up such questions after a few days, but upvoted / accepted answers block that process.

Comment: @PM2Ring are those questions only "answered" in comments then?

Comment: @What No, they're supposed to be closed and (gently) deleted.

Comment: Yes, we point out the typo in a comment, like  Aran-Fey did above. Generally, that's adequate, but if you feel that a full answer is warranted to explain some subtle feature of Python grammar, please feel free to write a full answer.